# Highcharts not displaying tooltip title properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts (technically the Highstock .js file though) to display a chart on my site. Everything works perfectly except the tooltip. The [API specifies](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.headerFormat) that `{series.name}` should work for specifying the series name in the tooltip, but the chart actually displays "{series.name}" instead of the name itself. [Here's a simplified jsFiddle that illustrates the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/8f337hwo/) Switch the comments on the `headerFormat:` lines in the `tooltip` section and you'll see that `{point.key}` works as expected, but `{series.name}` does not.

What's wrong with the code to produce this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known bug reported to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3572).

Workaround: Use a tooltip formatter and print all informations which you need.

Comment: Javascript isn't my strong suit; I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use `formatter`. Thank you though, I didn't realize it was a known bug!